# Can I restart my Mac remotely via screen sharing if the screen shows only linen?

Tags: mac, screen-sharing, reboot, back-to-my-mac

I am currently in Norway.  My Mac mini is in my apartment in Australia.  I can access screen sharing via Back To My Mac.  It connects fine, but the screen has only linen - no menu bar, no dock, no anything else.  I am fairly sure that is what is actually on the screen and that it isn't a problem with the connection or anything like that (it's happened once before while I was sitting in the same room...)

I know the system is responsive because the one other thing that can poke through my router is the Transmission web interface, and that works just fine.  (Unfortunately I seem to have neglected to forward a port for ssh...)

Is there any way I can reboot or otherwise regain full use of the system via the limited screen sharing access that I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently you can use the Back To My Mac infrastructure to get to SSH even if there's no port open on the router in front of the relevant Mac:

Find your iCloud account number by executing this command in terminal:

```
dns-sd -E
```

Example output

```
Looking for recommended registration domains:
Timestamp     Recommended Registration domain
23:45:15.660  Added     (More)               local
23:45:15.660  Added                          icloud.com
                                             - > btmm
                                             - - > members
                                             - - - > 123456789
```

(Make a note of the number on the last line, in this case *123456789* (this is just an example).

The hostname you need to use for ssh is <computer's local hostname>.<number above>.members.btmm.icloud.com.  Replace spaces with hyphens, and omit apostrophes (the default name is "Name's <type of Mac>")

The command I used therefore was:

```
ssh -2 -6 Jons-mac-mini.123456789.members.btmm.icloud.com
```

To complete the solution to my problem (rebooting), once logged in via SSH, I used the following command to restart:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

(Sourced from [here](http://webdiary.com/2011/12/27/btmm/))

Answer (score 0):

In this [page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) says that *Control-Eject* show you a shutdown dialog. (You need a keyboard with an *eject* key.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remotely restart the machine without having to specify the user then you can specify an input file in the form of a plist. Do the following steps on the computer that you are remoting into:

1. First you need to create a plist file that will have your
   credentials, open up a terminal window and paste the following:
   `touch ~/.restart.plist`. Now open up that plist file in a text
   editor and paste the following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>Username</key>
   <string>USERNAME_HERE</string>
   <key>Password</key>
   <string>PASSWORD_HERE</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
2. Replace USERNAME_HERE and PASSWORD_HERE in the file above with your credentials and save the file.
3. Create an alias in your bash profile so that all you
   have to do is type `reboot` and it will do the rest for you. Open up
   your ~/.bash_profile in a text editor and add the line `alias
   reboot="sudo fdesetup authrestart -inputplist < ~/.restart.plist"` then save the file.
4. Close and reopen your terminal window, or type in `source ~/.bash_profile` in order to update your alias to match the bash profile.

Now you'll be able to restart your remote computer with a specific user just by typing `reboot` into your terminal!

[Source](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/07/03/managing-macos-mojaves-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/)